Two strategies for the ODE $y'' + y = -2\sin x + 4x\cos x$. I understand the first. How do I continue with the second?
I am trying to solve the following ODE using two strategies:
$$
y'' + y = -2\sin x + 4x\cos x
$$
First strategy: Comparison of coefficients
Second strategy: Parameters variation
First Strategy: Using Comparison of coefficients I am getting the following result:
$
r^2 + 1 = 0 \implies r = \pm i \Rightarrow 
y_h = C_1\cos x + C_2\sin x$
and assuming $
y_p = \left(Ax^2 + Bx + C\right)\sin x + \left(Dx^2 + Ex + F\right)\cos x.
$,
I get, $
y_p' = \left(2Ax + B\right)\sin x + \left(Ax^2 + Bx + C\right)\cos x + \left(2Dx + E\right)\cos x - \left(Dx^2 + Ex + F\right)\sin x$ and
$
y_p'' = \left(2A\right)\sin x + \left(2Ax + B\right)\cos x + \left(2Ax + B\right)\cos x - \left(Ax^2 + Bx + C\right)\sin x + \left(2D\right)\cos x - \left(2Dx + E\right)\sin x - \left(Dx^2 + Ex + F\right)\cos x.$
Substituting in original equation I get:
$$y_p'' + y_p = \left(2A - 2E - 4D x\right)\sin x + \left(4A x + 2B + 2D\right)\cos x = 
-2\sin x + 4x\cos x.$$
I solved $
\begin{cases}
-4D = 0 \\
2A - 2E = -2 \\
4A = 4 \\
2B + 2D = 0
\end{cases}
$
$\Rightarrow$ $
y_p = x^2\sin x + 2x\cos x.
$
So: $$
y = y_h + y_p = C_1\cos x + C_2\sin x + x^2\sin x + 2x\cos x
$$
Second strategy: ($y_h$ same as above)Using variation of parameters I assume a solution of the form:
$
   y_p = u_1(x) \cos x + u_2(x) \sin x
   $ with the additional assumption that
$u_1' \cos x + u_2' \sin x = 0$.
So
$y_p' = u_1' \cos x - u_1 \sin x + u_2' \sin x + u_2 \cos x$
$y_p'' = (u_1'' \cos x - 2u_1' \sin x - u_1 \cos x) + (u_2'' \sin x + 2u_2' \cos x - u_2 \sin x)$
I substitute in original equation and get:
$(u_1'' \cos x - 2u_1' \sin x - u_1 \cos x) + (u_2'' \sin x + 2u_2' \cos x - u_2 \sin x) + u_1(x) \cos x + u_2(x) \sin x = -2\sin x + 4x\cos x$
which implies:
$u_1'' \cos x - 2u_1' \sin x + u_2'' \sin x + 2u_2' \cos x = -2\sin x + 4x\cos x$


My question is: How do I continue with this second strategy to get the solution (and is my solution in the first strategy is correct?)


Probably I have to use again my assumption that $u_1' \cos x + u_2' \sin x = 0$?
However, I don't see how

The easiest way to check if your first solution is correct is: does it satisfy the ODE, and does it have the right number of solutions? Since $\cos x,\sin x$ are clearly solutions to the homogeneous equation, the only tedious part to verify is the particular solution $y_p=x^2 \sin x+2x\cos x$ (and it does work). So your work via undetermined coefficients is valid.

We are trying to solve
$$y'' + y = -2\sin(x) + 4x\cos(x)$$
The first part of your solution is correct, but you could have chosen
$$Y_p(x) = x(a \cos(x) + b \sin(x)) + x(c~ x \cos(x) + d ~x \sin(x))$$
For the second part, we will use Paul's Notes on Variation of Parameters as a guide.
From the problem statement, we have
$$g(x) = -2\sin(x) + 4x\cos(x)$$
From your homogeneous solution $Y_h(x) = c_1 \cos(x) + c_2 \sin(x)$
$$y_1(x) = \cos(x), ~~~y_2(x) = \sin(x)$$
The Wronskian is
$$W(y_1(x), y_2(x)) = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{y_1(x)}&{y_2(x)}\\{ y_1'(x)}&{y_2'(x)}\end{array}} \right| = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{\cos \left( {x} \right)}&{\sin \left( {x} \right)}\\{ - \sin \left( {x} \right)}&{\cos \left( {x} \right)}\end{array}} \right| = {\cos ^2}\left( {x} \right) + {\sin ^2}\left( {x} \right) = 1$$
The particular solution is given by
$${Y_P}\left( x \right) =  - {y_1(x)}\int{{\frac{{{y_2(x)}g\left( x \right)}}{{W\left( {{y_1(x)},{y_2(x)}} \right)}}\,dx}} + {y_2}\int{{\frac{{{y_1}g\left( x \right)}}{{W\left( {{y_1(x)},{y_2(x)}} \right)}}\,dx}}$$
So, we have
$$Y_p(x) = -\cos(x) \int \dfrac{\sin(x) (-2\sin(x) + 4x\cos(x))}{1}\,dx + \sin(x) \int \dfrac{\cos(x) (-2\sin(x) + 4x\cos(x))}{1}\,dx$$
This results in
$$Y_p(x) = -\cos(x) (-x+\sin (2 x)+x (-\cos (2 x))) + \sin(x) (x^2+x \sin (2 x)+\cos ^2(x)+\frac{1}{2} \cos (2 x))$$
Simplifying
$$Y_P(x) = x^2 \sin (x)-\frac{\sin (x)}{2}+2 x \cos (x)$$
Now, you can write (the $-\frac{1}{2}$ term is absorbed into the $c_2$ constant since it is just another constant)
$$y(x) = Y_h(x) + Y_p(x) = c_1 \cos (x)+c_2 \sin (x)+ x^2 \sin (x)+2 x \cos (x)$$
Recall that ODEs allow us to verify that the solution satisfies the ODE and is correct by substituting the result into the original ODE and verifying that the LHS = RHS.

I'd quibble with the phrasing of the last sentence. We could, after all, plug the particular solution back in and verify LHS=RHS; it would nevertheless be false that this is the most general solutoin.

It does show linear superposition and that has value too. I suppose both should be explained separately for homogeneous vs particular vs linear combination.

@Semiclassical: By the way, do you have a recommendation for better phrasing? As an aside, I am quite interested in learning more about QM and QCs and things like Shor's algorithm. What would you consider the best source for that (I have looked at many), but I wanted something that went QFT step by step (for a small problem) - know of anything like that?
